# Page break after every section

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

The skeleton of my document is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,textcomp,amssymb,geometry,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{1.}

\begin{itemize}
\item[(a)]
\item[(b)]
\end{itemize}

\section*{2.}

\begin{itemize}
\item[(a)]
\item[(b)]
\end{itemize}

\section*{3.}

\begin{itemize}
\item[(a)]
\item[(b)]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I want each section to be on a separate page. How do I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

why

```
\section*{1.}
```

rather than

```
\section{}
```

In LaTeX it's almost always better to let LaTeX do the numbering.

However in either case

```
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\clearpage\oldsection}
```

will add the page break.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's `\section*{1.}`. I just copied this code from someone...

Do I add your code snippet to the preamble?

Comment: @FrankEpps it's a bad style, it disables the latex cross referencing mechanism as latex doesn't "know" the number and of course it means if you edit in a new section you have to renumber the whole document by hand.

Comment: @FrankEpps yes adding that to the preamble should work

Answer (score 9):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209065/to-have-no-pagebreak-after-include-in-latex)

If you place each section into its own file and place all the files into the same folder, you can easily determine whether you would like a page break or not between each by using `\include{section file}` or `\input{section file}`.

`\include{section file}` places a page break after each while `\input{section file}` does not.

```
\documentclass[notitlepage, 12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\title{Weekly Homework X}
\author{Tony Stark\\ 
Foundations of Mathematics}

\maketitle

\input{file example 1}
\input{file example 2}
\input{file example 3}

\include{file example 4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This was troubling me! I wanted to get rid of own pages for sections but I had no section break config anywhere

Answer (score 6):

Here's another option using `\sectionbreak` from the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleclass{\section}{top}
\newcommand\sectionbreak{\clearpage}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Test section one}
\section{Test section two}
\section{Test section three}
\section{Test section four}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if you also use `hyperref`. Or at least didn't work for me.

Comment: @Gonzalo Do you happen to know, if there is a way to turn this feature of for some specific headings?