# Page break after each section with title

Tags: macros, sectioning, page-breaking

I'd like to have there be a page break in between each section, just like in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131015/page-break-after-every-section), but I'd also like there to be no page break prior to the first section (that is, between the title and the first section). I'm currently using that question's best answer's suggestion:

```
\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\clearpage\stdsection}
```

but I can obviously change.

Comment: if there is text between the title and the first `\section`, do you still want no page break before the first `\section`?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `\clearpage` add a command that, the first time, redefines itself to be the same as `\clearpage`:

```
\let\latexsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\sectionbreak\latexsection}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\global\let\sectionbreak\clearpage}
```

Comment: Are you Sauron?

Comment: @synful No, I only practice TeX wizardry, which is surely white magic. ;-)

Comment: *which is whitespace magic

Answer (score 2):

This version resembles the version of egreg, but it regards the (total) section number, such, that there is **no** pagebreak just before the first section occurs (unless manually forced)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage{assoccnt}%



\let\LaTeXStandardSection\section
\newcounter{totalsection}%

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{section}{totalsection}

\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \ifnumequal{\number\value{totalsection}}{0}{%
  }{%
    \clearpage%
  }%
  \LaTeXStandardSection
}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First -- with no pagebreak}
\section{Second with pagebreak}%


\end{document}
```