# How automatically start a new page with the \section{} command

Tags: texshop, renewcommand

I want to renew the command `\section` such that it automatically starts a new page as well. This is also my first time using the `\renewcommand` macro, and I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct. It tried something like:

`\renewcommand{\section{}}{\newpage\section{}}`

And I suspect there is something that is supposed to go into the section arguments but I'm not sure. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Kindly check out this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/start-new-page-with-each-section .

Comment: Your `\renewcommand` will lead to an endless recursion, you should do something like `\let\oldsection\section` to save the original section and then `\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\clearpage\oldsection{#1}}`. See also this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131015/237192

Comment: Thanks, I will look into them

Comment: With an uptodate TeX distribution you can use `\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\clearpage}`.